# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cuAddress' cannot be null

Tags: sql, fetch, axios

I have been trying to save registration form data into the database using axios.This all works fine with a GET request, but it fails when I send a POST request and I kept on receiving this error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'cuAddress' cannot be null

using both Axios and Fetch.

It is working successfully with Ajax only.

Here is the source code:

```
var url = "https://www.webprogr.com/tmp/labs/www/mani/hyperlocal-restful/v1/booking";
                     var sData = ($(frmObj).serialize())
 axios(url, {


  method: 'post',
                        body: sData,
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": api_key
                        }
                    }).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        return response.data
                    }).then(function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                        console.log(sData)
                    })
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?
[ERROR STATEMENT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbQC.png)
Thanx in advance!

Comment: From the error it looks like you are providing NULL values to a Non Null key column(cuAddress)

Comment: no actually i gave a valid data..  I don't know.. This error is from server side or did i do anything wrong with axios?

Comment: They are showing in the console.log from the server, which means that my data is reaching the server.But data is not being saved in Database.

Comment: can you provide the table script